# php 5.x and ignoring <xml> tags?

Tags: php, escaping, html-entities

Here is a snippet of the code I'm trying to understand; in my web design class, I learned that php single quotes ' ' interpret everything literally, as a string. However, in this code:

```
$kml = array();  
$kml[] = '<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1">';  
$kml[] = ' <Document>';  
$kml[] = ' <Style id="hitStyle">';  
$kml[] = ' <IconStyle id="hitIcon">';  
$kml[] = ' <Icon>';  
$kml[] = ' <href>http://vkhovanskaya.net/images/glow.png</href>';  
$kml[] = ' </Icon>';  

$kmlOutput = $kml[5];
print($kmlOutput);
```

prints: "http://vkhovanskaya.net/images/glow.png"
and I need it to print `<href>http://vkhovanskaya.net/images/glow.png</href>` because it's part of 
what will be a kml file (I need the markup tags)

What should I be doing to escape the < > from interpretation attempts?

Comment: This seems a really bad way to build an XML document. Consider using [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) or [DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

Answer (score 0):

Interpolation from what?  A web browser will often try to parse it... but PHP isn't interpolating it, the web browser is.  Making sure you are using the right mime-type may help, but some browsers (like IE...) will often try to render everything vaguely like text as HTML.

FWIW, post code like:

```
$kml[] = '<href>http://vkhovanskaya.net/images/glow.png';
```

(Click the ? icon for help... transliterating characters makes things hard to read.)

If you really want to ensure a browser displays it, you'll need to escape the <'s as &lt;

Answer (score 0):

Are you displaying this in a browser? If so, view the page source and you should see your XML node as you expect.

If you want the markup to render as readable in an HTML document, use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) or [htmlentities](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

```
echo htmlspecialchars($kmlOutput);
```

Comment: Yes, it did show up in the source code, and echo htmlspecialchars($kmlOutput); works great. It all even goes copy/pastes into google earth!! Thanks!